# About the area of integer-edge-length triangles

Tags: number-theory, euclidean-geometry, triangles

Let $a,b,c$ be three edge lengths of a triangle whose area is $S$.

Then, here is my question.

> **Question** : Supposing that $a,b,c$ are natural numbers, then does there exists $(a,b,c)$ such that $S=6k$ for any $k\in\mathbb N$?

**Motivation** : I've known the following fact:

> **Fact** : If $a,b,c,S$ are natural numbers, then $S$ is a multiple of $6$.

**Proof** : By Heron's formula, we get
$$\begin{align}16S^2=(a+b+c)(-a+b+c)(a-b+c)(a+b-c).\qquad(\star)\end{align}$$
Hence, we know that in mod $2$
$$a+b+c\equiv -a+b+c\equiv a-b+c\equiv a+b-c.$$
If all of these are odd, we reach a contradiction. So we know that all of these are even. Here, letting 
$$x=\frac{-a+b+c}{2}, y=\frac{a-b+c}{2}, z=\frac{a+b-c}{2},$$
then, getting $\frac{a+b+c}{2}=x+y+z,$ we know 
$$(\star)\iff S^2=(x+y+z)xyz.$$

By considering in mod $3$, we know that $S^2$ can be divided by $3$, which means that $S$ can be divided by $3$.

By considering in mod $4$, we know that $S^2$ can be divided by $4$, which means that $S$ can be divided by $2$.

Now we know that $S$ can be divided by $6$ as desired. Hence, the proof is now completed.

This got me interested in the above question, but I'm facing difficulty. Can anyone help?

Comment: Do you mean "... for _every_ $k\in\mathbb N$"?

Comment: The areas are tabulated at http://oeis.org/A188158 but I don't see a formula. It appears there is no such triangle of area 18, nor 78, nor 102, nor 138, 162, 174, .... Related is http://oeis.org/A083875

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heronian_triangle shows some of the primitive cases.  No solutions for some multiples though, and no characterisation of which those multiples are. Of course if $A$ is feasible, so is $4A, 9A, etc$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Theorem**: There is no integer-sided triangle whose area is 18 units.

**Proof**: Assume such a triangle exists. Then there are integers $x, y, z$ such that $18^2 = xyz(x + y + z)$. Assume without loss of generality that $x \ge y \ge z$. Since $y \ge 1$ and $z \ge 1$, we have $x(x + 2) \le 18^2$ which certainly forces $x < 18$. This leaves us with only 17 possibilities for $x$ and hence $17 \times 18 / 2 = 153$ possibilities for the pair $(x, y)$; for each of these there is at most one $z$ which will work, and a moment's computer calculation shows that none of the 153 cases leads to a solution.

Comment: Thank you very much for nice answer!

Comment: Since both $x$ and $y$ divide $18^2$, there are fewer than 153 possibilities to try; no need to try $x=5,7,8,10,11,13,14,15,16,17$, same for $y$. Anyway, can you prove 78 is not an area? 102? 138?